# CMock mock some functions but not others from same module

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmock, ceedling

```
//myfuncs.h
void func1(void);

void func2(void;
```

I'm doing unit testing. Using CMock with ceedling, is there any way to mock func1(), but run func2() as it was originally written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't. You must split the header file into two and generate mocks for one of them.

There are unit test frameworks that can mock one or more functions in a header file, [Nala](https://github.com/eerimoq/nala) (which I'm maintaining) for example. But I guess you want to use CMock with Ceedling, so it's not really an option.